# IBM Liberty 23.x version is not taking hibernate jar from deployed application

Tags: websphere-liberty, hibernate-validator

Liberty 23.0.0.5 our application uses Hibernate validator for bean validation. We have Hibernate validator jar in our application lib which is not loaded rather it is using liberties validator. Hence.

we tried parent last class loader configuration.
 through server.xml which is also not effective.

Comment: Not sure what is your configuration as you didnt provide your server.xml in the question, but you can take a look at "JPA container" feature which allows you to override Liberty JPA provider with your own - https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/feature/persistenceContainer-3.1.html You should also not enable beanValidation feature if you dont want to use one provided by Liberty.